# eSIM - technology issue?

Tags: networking, communication

Let's consider a SmartWatch which has eSIM inside.
If the carrier is not supporting it, is there a chance that I can activate it?

Details: the SmartWatch in question is a Samsung one. My carrier is specified that it supports only Apple Watch as of now. I believe Apple has the very same technology as the Samsung in terms of the eSIM.

eSIM is normally a replacement of the traditional SIM cards, so I don't really see the thing if a provider is not supporting it, why it could not work.

ps.: Maybe this topic is not the right one but I really don't find any better for this question.

Comment: I don't know the details of the eSIM implementation, but there must at some point be a provisioning process where either data from the carrier is loaded onto the eSIM or alternatively, identifying information from the eSIM is sent to the carrier. So there needs to be a communication channel in place for this to happen, which may take a while to set up.

Comment: Just to clarify are you saying your provider doesn't support eSIMs or doesn't support your specific device?

Comment: My provider does support eSIM, and it is also specified their support for Apple Watch 5, but they don't specify Samsung's eSIM smartwatch.